# Gradle + Jacoco

Tags: gradle, jacoco

Was working prior to upgrading to Gradle 6.9.4 and Jacoco 0.8.6, but now when running "gradle test jacocoTestReport" I get:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.report.IReportGroupVisitor

I've added jacoco (agent, core, report) JARs to buildscript and subproject dependencies in build.gradle.

debug log shows the jacoco JARs in the Compiler arguments list, but they must not be present when jacocoTestReport is executed.

Is there a missing JAR? Is there a way to add it to the  jacocoTestReport task?